# Accessing the element on the basis of text - Selenium WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a ul , that contains 2 lists having same class name and all other properties, except their text value. See the HTML code below

Revised Code:

```
<table class="day-form-clause">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Buy Assets:</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group open">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in beforeOrAfter">
                            <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="setStartBeforeOrAfter(option)"> Trading Days Before </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in beforeOrAfter">
                            <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="setStartBeforeOrAfter(option)"> Trading Days After </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sell Assets:</td>
            <td>
                <div class="btn-group open">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in beforeOrAfter">
                            <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="setStartBeforeOrAfter(option)"> Trading Days Before </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="option in beforeOrAfter">
                            <a class="ng-binding" ng-click="setStartBeforeOrAfter(option)"> Trading Days After </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above code, there are two columns (Buy Assets) and (Sell Assets), and both of these columns have 2 lists each. The contents of the list (Text, properties) is exactly the same in both columns.

Now, if I use

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Trading Days Before')]")
```

Or

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu li:nth-of-type(2) > a[ng-click*='BeforeOrAfter']")
);
```

This returns me 2 matching nodes, one from the 'td = Buy Assets' and the other from the 'td = Sell Assets'.

What if I only want to access the text (Trading Days Before) from 'td = Buy Assets'. How would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Use xpath and select by text:

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Trading Days Before')]")`
and
`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Trading Days After')]")`

Comment: What about if my code exists for 2 columns, like I have above code block for <td> Buy Assets </td>, and the same block of code for  <td> Sell Assets </td>. Your above solution returns me 2 matching nodes, one from Buy assets and the other from Sell assets

Answer (score 0):

Using `JavaScriptExecutor`. This would work.

Sample example

```
String jScript = "var myList = document.getElementsByClassName(\"selectBox-label\");" + "myList[0].innerHTML=\"YourNumber\";";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript(jScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, this positioning will be static, so it would most likely be safe to use :nth-of-type css, and NOT on the basis of text.

Something like this would work:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu li:nth-of-type(2) > a[ng-click*='BeforeOrAfter']")
);
```

My reasoning for this, is because of logic.  Logic dictates that if "after" is ever before "before", than that would be an app bug anyway.  Anytime you see "Before and after" in succession, it's respective.  "Before" should always be BEFORE "after" hence `:nth-of-type(2)` being after, and `:nth-of-type(1)` being before.

I'm merely offering an alternate perspective that will solve your issue without the need of text matching.

**EDIT**: Same thing regarding Buy / Sell.  Assuming that the Buy and Sell will not change, you could just add `tr:nth-of-type(2)` for the sell, and `tr:nth-of-type(1)` for the buy.

```
WebElement buyTradingDaysBefore = driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu tr:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-of-type(1) > a[ng-click*='BeforeOrAfter']")
);

WebElement buyTradingDaysAfter = driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu tr:nth-of-type(1) li:nth-of-type(2) > a[ng-click*='BeforeOrAfter']")
);

WebElement sellTradingDaysBefore = driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu tr:nth-of-type(2) li:nth-of-type(1) > a[ng-click*='BeforeOrAfter']")
);

WebElement sellTradingDaysAfter = driver.findElement(
  By.cssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu tr:nth-of-type(2) li:nth-of-type(2) > a[ng-click*='BeforeOrAfter']")
);
```

Comment: You are right, I can access data like that but I have an other issue. Please see the revised HTML code and description, and guide me. Thanks